# Trouble using $group twice in mongodb aggregation query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let me start off by saying I am new to mongo and node.js. For each client I work with, I am looking at the past week of traffic to find the max and min of six variables and their dates. Right now mongo aggregation takes care of some of the work but I am convinced that it can do more. Right now my pipeline is the following:

1. $match - only return documents within the past week
2. $group - group by client and by date
3. $project - calculate some values

And documents are returned in the following manor:

```
{ _id: 
   { client: "aRandomClientNameWouldBeHere",
     date: Thu Jun 04 46370 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) },
  impSales: 0,
  pixSales: 0,
  apiSales: 0,
  s2sSales: 0,
  clicks: 3,
  impressions: 0 }
```

I am having trouble adding another $group stage to the pipeline, grouping over just clients and getting the dates that the max and min occur for each field.

I need something like this:

```
$group: { 
  _id: "$client" ,
  maxImpSales: { $max: impSales },
  maxImpSalesDate : { ??? },
  minImpSales: { $min: impSales },
  minImpSalesDate : { ??? },
  ...
}
```

However, I cant get it to work for two reasons.

1. I don't know how to group just by client since client is now in the _id field along with date. (i.e. do I use _id: "$client" or _id : _id.client or something else?)
2. How can I embed the date that the min and the max occurred?

How do I do 1 & 2? Thanks. Below is my 3 stage pipeline

```
{
  $match:
  {
    date:
    {
      $gte: _.last(dutil.lastXDates(6))
    }
  }
},
{
  $group:
  {
    _id:
    {
      client: "$client",
      date: "$date"
    },
    z1is: { $sum: "$actions.sales.import.z1.count" },
    z2is: { $sum: "$actions.sales.import.z2.count" },
    z3is: { $sum: "$actions.sales.import.z3.count" },
    z1ps: { $sum: "$actions.sales.pixel.z1.count" },
    z2ps: { $sum: "$actions.sales.pixel.z2.count" },
    z3ps: { $sum: "$actions.sales.pixel.z3.count" },
    z1as: { $sum: "$actions.sales.apiOnly.z1.count" },
    z2as: { $sum: "$actions.sales.apiOnly.z2.count" },
    z3as: { $sum: "$actions.sales.apiOnly.z3.count" },
    z1ss: { $sum: "$actions.sales.s2s.z1.count" },
    z2ss: { $sum: "$actions.sales.s2s.z2.count" },
    z3ss: { $sum: "$actions.sales.s2s.z3.count" },
    z1ic: { $sum: "$actions.click.import.z1.count" },
    z2ic: { $sum: "$actions.click.import.z2.count" },
    z3ic: { $sum: "$actions.click.import.z3.count" },
    z1pc: { $sum: "$actions.click.pixel.z1.count" },
    z2pc: { $sum: "$actions.click.pixel.z2.count" },
    z3pc: { $sum: "$actions.click.pixel.z3.count" },
    z1ac: { $sum: "$actions.click.apiOnly.z1.count" },
    z2ac: { $sum: "$actions.click.apiOnly.z2.count" },
    z3ac: { $sum: "$actions.click.apiOnly.z3.count" },
    z1sc: { $sum: "$actions.click.s2s.z1.count" },
    z2sc: { $sum: "$actions.click.s2s.z2.count" },
    z3sc: { $sum: "$actions.click.s2s.z3.count" },
    z1ii: { $sum: "$actions.display.import.z1.count" },
    z2ii: { $sum: "$actions.display.import.z2.count" },
    z3ii: { $sum: "$actions.display.import.z3.count" },
    z1pi: { $sum: "$actions.display.pixel.z1.count" },
    z2pi: { $sum: "$actions.display.pixel.z2.count" },
    z3pi: { $sum: "$actions.display.pixel.z3.count" },
    z1ai: { $sum: "$actions.display.apiOnly.z1.count" },
    z2ai: { $sum: "$actions.display.apiOnly.z2.count" },
    z3ai: { $sum: "$actions.display.apiOnly.z3.count" },
    z1si: { $sum: "$actions.display.s2s.z1.count" },
    z2si: { $sum: "$actions.display.s2s.z2.count" },
    z3si: { $sum: "$actions.display.s2s.z3.count" }
  }
},
{
  $project:
  {
    totalCountImpSales: { $add: ["$z1is", "$z2is", "$z3is"] },
    totalCountImpClicks: { $add: ["$z1ic", "$z2ic", "$z3ic"] },
    totalCountImpImpressions: { $add: ["$z1ii", "$z2ii", "$z3ii"] },
    totalCountPixSales: { $add: ["$z1ps", "$z2ps", "$z3ps"] },
    totalCountPixClicks: { $add: ["$z1pc", "$z2pc", "$z3pc"] },
    totalCountPixImpressions: { $add: ["$z1pi", "$z2pi", "$z3pi"] },
    totalCountApiSales: { $add: ["$z1as", "$z2as", "$z3as"] },
    totalCountApiClicks: { $add: ["$z1ac", "$z2ac", "$z3ac"] },
    totalCountApiImpressions: { $add: ["$z1ai", "$z2ai", "$z3ai"] },
    totalCountS2sSales: { $add: ["$z1ss", "$z2ss", "$z3ss"] },
    totalCountS2sClicks: { $add: ["$z1sc", "$z2sc", "$z3sc"] },
    totalCountS2sImpressions: { $add: ["$z1si", "$z2si", "$z3si"] }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your whole aggregation pipeline and a sample source document in your question. Right now you grouping with only a single date. It seems what you actually want are the "min" and "max" date for particular types.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this.  Add a `$sort` phase after your `$project` and then use the [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [`$last`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operators in the `$group` phase to get the min and max values.  That is:

```js
...
// Sort by impSales ascending
{
    $sort: { impSales: 1}
},
{
$group: { 
  _id: "$_id.client" ,
  maxImpSales: { $last: "$impSales" },
  maxImpSalesDate : { $last: "$_id.date" },
  minImpSales: { $first: "$impSales" },
  minImpSalesDate : { $first: "$_id.date" },
  ...
}
}
...
```

Comment: So I would have to use a $sort then $group for each data field? That seems pretty messy to me but I guess it is a whole lot cleaner than doing it in node.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I agree it is messy.  But that seems to be the only way to achieve what you want, at least that I'm aware of.

Comment: I am now getting results that look like this:                          { _id: null,
  maxImp: null,
  maxImpDate: null,
  minImp: null,
  minImpDate: null }. results.length is returning one which is weird.

Comment: Can you look at results after the $sort phase (and maybe filter for just one client just for testing), so you can manually verify the max and min values?

Comment: The problem is that after the first $sort and $group, all of the clients are already grouped, so next time we try to group, there is only one instance of each id (client) because we have already grouped by id. Is there any way to ungroup? Everything works perfect with only one $sort and $group.

Comment: Gotcha!  I see the issue.  I'll post here if I can think of a better way to do this than run separate queries for each field.

Comment: Thanks, if that is the case then I will just keep my 3 stage pipeline and do the rest with node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57187/discussion-between-isaac9a-and-anand-jayabalan).